# Remove <br> from column headers in tabulator xlsx export

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, xlsx, tabulator

I am using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) as frontend table framework in my browser. Some of my columns have long titles and are splitted by html line breaks (`<br>`).

When I [download the table data in Excel file format](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/download#xlsx), my column headers (= first row in this spreadsheet export) contain those `<br>` as plain text, e.g.: `Foo<br>bar`.

How can I remove these characters in my excel export? Is this even possible? Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here a screenshot from my Excel export for clarification:
[image: Tabulator Column Headers in Excel]

Comment: I'm not clear on this. Are the ```<br>``` created by you as part of the title or by Tabulator when it wraps the titles? You do have an option to specify a download title [Download Title](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/download#advanced-title)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I inserted the `<br>` as part of the title. Huge thanks for the link! Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the title you want to be substituted for in the download here  [Download Title](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/download#advanced-title) as:

```
columns: [
    { title: "Name", field: "name", titleDownload: "Full Name" } //change column title to "Full Name" in download
]
```

If you really want to customize things you build your own custom file formatter [Custom Format](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/download#custom).